# How to create a custom colorscheme in which define custom highlight group each of containing set of words?

Tags: vimrc, linux

Let's assume we want to create a custom colorscheme. For example, content of a custom colorscheme file `~/.vim/colors/mytheme.vim` are as follows,

```
" syntax highlighting groups
hi Comment  guifg=#007f7f
hi Constant guifg=#ffa0a0
```

As you can see in above code snippet, I am just defining colors for default highlight groups.

1. How can add extend default highlight group? i.e. I want to add some words to be considered under `Comment` group.
2. How to create new highlight group e.g. `StylishComments`? And similarly add few words under that group?

Comment: A colorsheme file defines colors for groups. A syntax file defines what elements the groups consist of. These are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't/shouldn't "create a custom colorscheme in which define custom highlight group each of containing set of words".

What you can/should do:

1. define your colorscheme file where for the color groups specific colors are defined (example snip):

```
set background=dark

hi clear
if exists('syntax_on')
    syntax reset
endif

let g:colors_name = 'mycolorscheme'

hi Comment  guifg=#007f7f
hi Constant guifg=#ffa0a0
"... other color groups if needed. Otherwise default values would be used.
```

2. define syntax file that create syntax elements such as comments, keywords, constants, etc and maps them to colorgroups (existing or created by you), for example for asciidoctor syntax I have:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

syn match asciidoctorComment "^//.*$"

hi def link asciidoctorComment               Comment
" ... other syntax elements
```

Where I define what is asciidoctor comment -- something that start with double slash in the beginning of the line till the end of the line -- and map it to default Comment highlight group.

And to be closer to your questions:

1. you can try to do explicit:

```
syntax match Comment "hello\|world"
```

That would make words "hello" and "world" a comment, kind of. Although it would be overwritten when you open a new file with defined syntax, so you should have find a way to properly execute this after current syntax file was loaded. (`:h autocommand`)

2. Well it is the same, but you have to add highlight for that group:

```
syntax match StylishComments "My\|Stylish\|Comments"
hi StylishComments guifg="#ffff00"
```

Here is the same issue as with pt.1 but it also will probably overwritten after you change colorscheme.

You can try it in vim session `:syntax ...` to see if it works for you (it worked for me:). Then decide what route to go, either using autocommands in vimrc to reapply those commands after filetype and/or colorscheme was changed or create a proper syntax and colorscheme files.